# Is the bundle in fragment getArgs() the same object that is passed through setArgs()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, bundle

If I set arguments of a fragment myfragment to a Bundle mybundle, am I guaranteed that if I change the contents of mybundle later down the road, myfragment's call to getArguments() will be consistent with the contents of mybundle?

i.e.

```
mybundle.putString("background", "red");
myfragment.setArguments(mybundle);
```

... later ...

```
mybundle.putString("background", "orange");
myfragment.createLayoutFromBundle(myfragment.getArguments());
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Check the [source code for the `Fragment` class](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.java). The bundle is not copied or anything, just returned as-is.

```
    public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
        if (mIndex >= 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment already active");
        }
        mArguments = args;
    }

/**
* Return the arguments supplied when the fragment was instantiated,
* if any.
*/
    final public Bundle getArguments() {
        return mArguments;
    }
```

Comment: There are other places where `mArguments` is assigned.

Comment: @CommonsWare Really? I guess you should know, but I didn't see them (except for rotation, but it's explicitly said that they are the same then).

Comment: The `Bundle` is part of the saved instance state (see `FragmentState` in the source). In cases where the saved instance state is rebuilt from scratch, the `Bundle` will be rebuilt as well. See my answer to the question for more.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments `Bundle` is part of the fragment's saved instance state. If the fragment is destroyed and re-created, your newly-created fragment will have an arguments `Bundle` with the same *contents* as did the original `Bundle`. However, the `Bundle` object may be different.

This will most easily seen when:

- the user is in your fragment, with the `Bundle`
- the user presses HOME
- your process is terminated (you can test this via DDMS)
- the user returns to your fragment via the recent-tasks list

You will have the same data in the `Bundle` as before, but the `Bundle` object will be newly-created.

Comment: That is true, but is there any practical difference? Of course the instance will be different if the process is terminated -- it just seemed irrelevant to the original question (call to getArguments() _will be consistent with the contents_ of mybundle?)

Comment: @matiash: In most apps, it should not have any practical difference. However, in terms of the current title of the question, `getArguments()` does not have to return the same object as `setArguments()` supplied, depending upon when `getArguments()` is called.

Comment: OK, with the title, you're right. However, the question text said otherwise :) I though it obvious that the instance would not be the _same_ if the app is terminated and recreated from its old state... however its contents will be.

Comment: @matiash: It may be obvious to you and me; it might not be obvious to others reading the question, particularly if they stumble upon it in a search. In effect, we're both right -- within the lifetime of a specific fragment *instance*, the arguments `Bundle` instance will not change except via `setArguments()`. A reconstituted fragment will have a similarly-reconstituted `Bundle`.